# Quick way of matching date range to indices in Python list of dates

Tags: python, list, datetime, python-2.7

I need to select the index of the earliest date which is no more than `interval` days before `date1` (with index `i1`). I have a sorted list `dates` and this is the snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
for i1 in mylist:
    date1 = dates[i1]
    i0 = sum(1 for d in dates if date1 - d > timedelta(days = interval))
    # do some other stuff with this
```

The line where I find `i0` seems to be the bottleneck of this loop, because if I change it to `i0 = max(0, i1 - 30)` (which simply ignores missing dates), it works about 100 times quicker.

Is there a way to speed it up? I feel like there should be a way of using the fact that the list is sorted and avoid doing all the comparisons.

---

PS: My first try at it was:

```
i0 = len([d for d in dates if date1 - d > timedelta(days = interval)])
```

which is even slower.

Comment: Is `dates` already ordered? And related to that, is `i0` the index of the first by order or the first temporally?

Comment: you could try binary search: `i = bisect.bisect_left(dates, dates[i1]-timedelta(days=interval))`

Comment: Another thing to try -- outside of the `bisect` module's recipes on ["searching sorted lists"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) -- would be to use something like the two-pointer sliding window approach.  Loop over each date and have a lagging index incrementing until the lagged date plus the interval is >= the date.

Comment: Dates are ordered, yes. `i0` is the first date which is within `interval` days from `date1`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That did work and produced the needed speedup. Please make it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't understand the outer loop (with `i1`). If you need to find the date for *all* possible `i1` then there might be better than `O(n*log n)`-time algorithm.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I need to find index, not date itself. But yes, I need this for all possible `i1` values.

Comment: Yeah, I see where you are going with this - after each `i1` increment we can go and shift `i0` if needed as well... Certainly more efficient than doing the search every time. Anyway, I'll edit the question to match your answer, because this is what I really asked about and your answer is perfect. But I see now that I can rewrite the loop in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to select the index of the earliest date which is no more than `interval` days before date1 (with index `i1`). I have a sorted list `dates`

Using binary search (`O(log n)` time complexity):

```
import bisect

i = bisect.bisect_left(dates, dates[i1]-timedelta(days=interval))
```

Paraphrasing [`bisect`'s documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html): the return value `i` is such that all dates in the slice `dates[:i]` are *more than* (`>`) `interval` days before `date[i1]`, and all dates in the slice `dates[i:]` are *less than or exactly* (`<=`) `interval` days before `dates[i1]`.